# Putting 2 divs at opposite sides

Tags: html, css

Trying to put one div on the right side, other one on the left.
I have 1 div with 2 divs inside.

`float: right` to parent div and text/image.

```
<div class="navigation">       

    <div class="left">      
        <img src="Logo.png" id="logoImage">
        <h1>TWITCHBOOK</h1>     
    </div>  

    <div class="right">
        <h3>Luka Crypto</h3>      
        <div id="circle"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/Cryptooo/pen/rXGdoP

Two divs on opposite sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by styling `.navigation` as a flexbox with `justify-content: space-between;`:

```css
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left {
  background: red;
}

.right {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="Logo.png" id="logoImage">
    <h1>TWITCHBOOK</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <h3>Luka Crypto</h3>
    <div id="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

From your codepen, the `.navigation` element is a flex container. So, remove the `float: right` on the `.right` element and add `margin-left: auto` to "push" it over to the right side.

```
.right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

This is recommended from the flexbox spec in [Aligning with auto margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="left">
    <h3>TWITCHBOOK</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <h3>Luka Crypto</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```